# Can't move one folder from external HD to internal HD

Tags: hard-drive, parallels-desktop, file-transfer

So there is one folder that can't move from my external HD to my internal HD. There are many other folders that I have successfully moved, but this one is stubborn.

Every time I try to move it, I get this error: `The Finder can't complete the operation because some data in "Microsoft Windows XP.pvm" can't be read or written`

I have tried using terminal to move the folder with no success. `sudo cp -R /Volumes/320\ GO\ Backup/backup\ 2015/Parallels /Users/Max/Desktop` gives me: `cp /Volumes/320 GO Backup/backup 2015/Parallels/Microsoft Windows XP.pvm/winxp.hdd/winxp.hdd.0.{5fbaabe3-6958-40ff-92a7-860e329aab41}.hds: Input/output error`

Other things I have tried with no success:

- The `dot_clean` command in terminal.
- Reparing with the disk utility
- Used Carbon Copy Cloner
- Did all those operations in Safe mode

I'm really stuck!! Any help is appreciated :).

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you must fully shut down the Windows XP virtual machine before you can move its .pvm package. If the virtual machine is running, it will have a "file busy" flag attached which prevents copying.

Comment: @DocG. Right, already done.

Comment: Have you tried running cp in Single User mode?

Comment: Tried using Parallels to either Clone or Reclaim disk space?

Comment: @DocG. Just tried `cp` in Single User mode. No success :(. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Tetsujin I just tried your suggestion. Using the "clone" function fails and "reclaim disk space" seems to have no effect at all (a.k.a. the disk space isn't reclaimed).

Answer (score 1):

This unfortunately indicates a disk error...
I suggest digging up snapshots of previous virtual machines and seeing if you can restore the .pvm to one of those previous, working, versions.  Back up the VM somewhere first and maybe even fire it up to back up the data inside.

I would also look through the Console (Applications/Utilities/Console.app) to see if more disk I/O errors are being logged, because this is typically in my experience the first sign of a failing hard-drive.